# Get VirtualMachineScaleSet instanceview for a ResourceGroup

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-for-java

I am trying to get instanceview objects(VirtualMachineScaleSetInstanceViewInner) of all Azure's VirtualMachineScaleSets under a Subscription and this requires both ResourceGroup Name and Vmss name together.

```
azureResourceManager.virtualMachines().manager().serviceClient().getVirtualMachineScaleSets().getInstanceView(resourceGroupName, virtualMachineScaleSet.name(), Context.NONE);
```

How do I get specific VirtualMachineScaleSets under a ResourceGroup? I only see AzureResourceManager.ResourceGroups() and AzureResourceManager.virtualMachineScaleSets(), but nothing that gets virtualMachineScaleSets under a ResourceGroup.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to get the VMSS instance in a Resource group by using the below RestApi:

```
 GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/{vmScaleSetName}?api-version=2022-08-01
```

output:
[image]
[image]

**Body**:

```json
    {
      "name": "rajtestVMSS",
      "id": "/subscriptions/*********/resourceGroups/abcaaaa/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/rajtestVMSS",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets",
      "location": "westus2",
      "tags": {
        "azsecpack": "nonprod",
        "platformsettings.host_environment.service.platform_optedin_for_rootcerts": "true"
      },
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_D2s_v3",
        "tier": "Standard",
        "capacity": 2
      },
      "properties": {
        "singlePlacementGroup": false,
        "upgradePolicy": {
          "mode": "Manual"
        },
        "scaleInPolicy": {
          "rules": [
            "Default"
          ]
        },
        "virtualMachineProfile": {
          "osProfile": {
            "computerNamePrefix": "rajtestvm",
            "adminUsername": "rajtest",
            "windowsConfiguration": {
              "provisionVMAgent": true,
              "enableAutomaticUpdates": true,
              "enableVMAgentPlatformUpdates": false
            ------------------
            ------------------
            ------------------
```

You can use the below java code to get the VirtualMachine ScaleSet instanceview for a ResourceGroup.

```java
 import com.azure.core.util.Context;
 
 public final class Main {
     public static void getAVirtualMachineScaleSet(com.azure.resourcemanager.AzureResourceManager azure) {
         azure
             .virtualMachines()
             .manager()
             .serviceClient()
             .getVirtualMachineScaleSets()
             .getByResourceGroupWithResponse("myResourceGroup", "myVirtualMachineScaleSet", null, Context.NONE);
     }
 }
```

Thanks to @XiaofeiCao for the [github link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/azure-resourcemanager_2.19.0/sdk/resourcemanager/azure-resourcemanager/README.md) to know more about Azure Resource Manager client library for Java.